# Find unknown tag containing given text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

My HTML is like :

```
<body>
  <div class="afds">
    <span class="dfsdf">mytext</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sdf dzf">
    <h1>some random text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to find all tags containing "**text**" & their corresponding classes. In this case, I want:

- span, "dfsdf"
- h1, null

Next, I want to be able to navigate through the returned tags. For example, find the *div* parent tag & respective classes of all the returned tags.

If I execute the following

```
soupx.find_all(text=re.compile(".*text.*"))
```

it simply returns the text part of the tags:

```
['mytext', ' some random text']
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something along these lines:

```
ts = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(".*text.*"))
for t in ts:
    if len(t.parent.attrs)>0:
        for k in t.parent.attrs.keys():
            print(t.parent.name,t.parent.attrs[k][0])
    else:
        print(t.parent.name,"null")
```

Output:

```
span dfsdf
h1 null
```

Answer (score 1):

find_all() does not return just strings, it returns [bs4.element.NavigableString](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring).
That means you can call other beautifulsoup functions on those results.

Have a look at find_parent and find_parents: [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent)

```
childs = soupx.find_all(text=re.compile(".*text.*"))
for c in childs:
    c.find_parent("div")
```